# _UIRemoteView - reveal view hierarchy in Xcode

Tags: ios, debugging, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

I'd like to see, how the Apple's UI frameworks are composed, in particular, the `ContactsUI`. However, when I try to *Debug View Hierarchy* in Xcode, I see only the blank `_UIRemoteView`.

Is there any way to peek inside the view hierarchy of the contact composer view?

**On the left** - how the composer looks like .
**On the right** - what's visible in the Xcode view hierarchy debugger

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UIRemoteView` is a view that lives in some other process. In this case there is likely some XPC service that the Contacts app uses to supply other applications with contact records and UI to edit them. Because the view is in another process, you can't see how it's made by looking at the view hierarchy in your own process.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The view hierarchy isn't provided by your process, so you don't have access to it.